I'm stuck trying to serve the tiles
I run quickstart.sh successfully
Now I'd like to serve my tiles locally
the QUICKSTART.md file suggests

Hints for designers: make start-maputnik # start Maputnik Editor +
dynamic tile server [ see http://localhost:8088 ] make stop-maputnik #
stop Maputnik Editor + dynamic tile server make start-postserve #
start dynamic tile server [ see http://localhost:8090 ] make
stop-postserve # stop dynamic tile server make start-tileserver #
start maptiler/tileserver-gl [ see http://localhost:8080 ] make
stop-tileserver # stop maptiler/tileserver-gl

but when I issue
sudo make start-maputnik

I get
$ sudo make start-maputnik
Using docker compose V1 (docker-compose)
docker-compose stop maputnik_editor
Starting postgres docker compose target using default image (no recreate if exists)
Starting openmaptiles_postgres_1 ... done
Wait for PostgreSQL to start...
docker-compose run --rm --user=0:0 openmaptiles-tools pgwait
Creating openmaptiles_openmaptiles-tools_run ... done

***********************************************************
*
* Bring up postserve at http://localhost:8090
*     --> can view it locally (use make start-maputnik)
*     --> or can use https://maputnik.github.io/editor
*
*  set data source / TileJSON URL to http://localhost:8090
*
***********************************************************

docker-compose up -d postserve
Starting openmaptiles_postserve_1 ... done

***********************************************************
*
* Start maputnik/editor
*       ---> go to http://localhost:8088
*       ---> set data source / TileJSON URL to http://localhost:8090
*
***********************************************************

docker-compose up -d maputnik_editor
Starting openmaptiles_maputnik_editor_1 ... done

then it returns the prompt and there’s no service running locally, as far as I can tell
What am I doing wrong ?
